# IO.FileSystemWatcher not working after Windows Update version 1709

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, file-watcher

I have a powershell script that watches a folder for file changes. After installing the Windows 10 Creators update 1709, the File watcher is no longer being triggered when files are saved.

We have a few others on the team that are seeing the same issue, does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?